# How do I scroll the output of less command without a mouse?

Tags: linux, scrolling

I am playing with OWASP-BWA in a VM to learn security in web-apps. If you are familiar with it you'll know that the linux doesn't have any GUI. I haven't installed VMWare tools on the machine because I don't really need to. I want to see a  list of services running on the the machine. So when I give `service --status-all` the page scrolls up and I see only the last few services (as the screen size of the VM is very small). So, I used the `service --status-all | less` command, I thought I could scroll the output with the up/down keys. Can anybody tell why this happens and how do I scroll the output?

Answer (score 6):

> Less Command – Screen Navigation
>
> Use the following screen navigation commands while viewing large log files.
>
> CTRL+F – forward one window
>      CTRL+B – backward one window
>      CTRL+D – forward half window
>      CTRL+U – backward half window
>
> Less Command – Line navigation
>
> In a smaller chunk of data, where you want to locate particular error, you may want to navigate line by line using these keys:
>
> j – navigate forward by one line
>      k – navigate backward by one line
>
> Less Command – Other Navigations
>
> The following are other navigation operations that you can use inside the less pager.
>
> G – go to the end of file
>      g – go to the start of file
>      q or ZZ – exit the less pager

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-less-command-10-tips-for-effective-navigation/